# how to load multiple images with universal image loader in android on gridview

Tags: android

please help me to get rid from this problem::::I've implemented the view holder pattern which is meant to reuse items. every time i reload the application

public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;

ImageLoader mLoader;
LayoutInflater inflater;
DisplayImageOptions options;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    // this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    // .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mLoader = mLoader;
    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(context,
            "your folder");// for caching

    // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
    mLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context)
            // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
            .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
            // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
            .enableLogging().build();
    // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
    mLoader.init(config);
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()

            // display stub image untik image is loaded
            .cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infl
                .inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        assert convertView != null;
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    mLoader.displayImage(
            "http://pin.muction.com/app/webroot/img/b0e485evideocon_logo.jpg",
            holder.imageView, options);

    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageView)
            .execute(OperatorsActivity.img_path[position]);

    return convertView;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(bmImage);

        this.bmImage = bmImage;

    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Log.i("path", urldisplay);
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(
                    "http://pin.muction.com/app/webroot/img/" + urldisplay)
                    .openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (imageViewReference != null && result != null) {
            bmImage = imageViewReference.get();
            if (bmImage != null) {
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: And why do you even have an AsyncTask ? The library does everything with the DisplayImage method. Remove it.

Comment: my problem is that when i  open this activity  images load but they change their position or some times images got change..

Comment: "http://pin.muction.com/app/webroot/img/  this link is of images link and contain many images i want to load only those images according to the web services but other images are also loaded and disturb the gridview items

Comment: To the displayImage, pass `OperatorsActivity.img_path[position]` and remove the async task.

Comment: i was did it but application got crashed. imageloader load only one image on whole gridview...

Comment: i want to use this link "http://pin.muction.com/app/webroot/img/" in the loader but if i use this link it will not show anything